# Exploding memory usage in Javafx WebView while loading many pages

Tags: javafx, webview, out-of-memory

i ran into a problem while handling with the WebView in Javafx.
The memory usage in my task-manager rises beyond everything and ends in a crash.

I have a simple code-example to recreate the problem:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewSample extends Application {

    public boolean cycle = false;

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        launch(); 
    }

    @Override public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() { 
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> obs, Worker.State old, Worker.State current) {

                if(javafx.concurrent.Worker.State.SUCCEEDED == current) {
                    if(cycle) {
                        engine.load("http://www.google.com");
                    } else {
                        engine.load("http://www.yahoo.com");
                    }
                    cycle = !cycle;
                }
            }
        });

        engine.load("http://www.google.com");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(webView));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

So basicly the code just loads two websites alternating! My problem isnt just with these two Pages, in my main program im loading all different URLs. But this recreates the Problem as well.

I´ve tried so far:

- calling the System.gc()
- building a URLStreamHandlerFactory to prevent image-loading
- calling engine.getHistory().setMaxSize(0)
- i monitored the process with visualvm - and found that the memory usage isnt exploding there
- engine.load("about:blank") between loading pages
- Googling for 3 days, to any kind of solution

Im really not shure if this is because of a mistake in my example, i missed something or a natural thing...

Im glad for any help, thx!

- Java 1.8.0_77

Answer (score 0):

**Edited 22/07/2016:
Apparently this is fixed in JDK 9: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8159594**

---

We've also seen similar behavior using JDK 1.8.0_92.

Just alternating between these two pages causes memory usage to climb uncontrollably.

Page1:

```
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Page 1</h1>
  <script>
    window.location.href = "page2.html";
  </script>
</body>
```

Page 2:

```
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Page 2</h1>
  <script>
    window.location.href = "page1.html";
  </script>
</body>
```

We are currently unable to find any solution to this apparent memory leak.

Comment: @jewelsea To be fair the OP didn't actually ask a question. They stated "Im really not shure if this is because of a mistake in my example" in response to which I have confirmed that we have also seen this problem i.e. it is unlikely to be their mistake.